# Tkinter / Pmw -- Centering Frame Inside Notebook Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

What I'm trying to do is get the frame with the two buttons (sframe) centered inside of the notebook (master) frame. This works without issue on Python 2.4 but on Python 2.7 the frame is anchored to NW by default. I know if I rowconfigure() / columnconfigure() the master page frame the inner frame will center itself but this solution doesn't seem correct. Disabling propagation and changing row/column weights don't seem to help either. Is there anyway to just get that inner frame centered properly? Here is the test code I'm working with:

```
import Tkinter as tk, Tkinter
import Pmw

class SimpleApp(object):
  def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
    title = kwargs.pop('title')
    master.configure(bg='blue')
    sframe = tk.Frame(master, relief=tk.RIDGE, bd=5, width=100,bg='green')
    sframe.grid()
    button = tk.Button(sframe, text = title)
    button.grid(sticky = tk.W)
    button = tk.Button(sframe, text = 'next')
    button.grid(sticky = tk.E)
    #sframe.propagate(0)
    #master.rowconfigure(0, minsize = 300)
    #master.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 300)

class Demo:
  def __init__(self, parent):
    # Create and pack the NoteBook.
    notebook = Pmw.NoteBook(parent)
    notebook.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

    # Add the "Appearance" page to the notebook.
    page = notebook.add('Helpers')
    app = SimpleApp(page, title= 'hello, world')
    notebook.tab('Helpers').focus_set()
    page = notebook.add('Appearance')

    # Create the "Toolbar" contents of the page.
    group = Pmw.Group(page, tag_text = 'Toolbar')
    group.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    b1 = Tkinter.Checkbutton(group.interior(), text = 'Show toolbar')
    b1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    b2 = Tkinter.Checkbutton(group.interior(), text = 'Toolbar tips')
    b2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    # Create the "Startup" contents of the page.
    group = Pmw.Group(page, tag_text = 'Startup')
    group.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    home = Pmw.EntryField(group.interior(), labelpos = 'w',
        label_text = 'Home page location:')
    home.pack(fill = 'x', padx = 20, pady = 10)

    page = notebook.add('Images')

    notebook.setnaturalsize()

def basic():
  root = tk.Tk()
  #app = SimpleApp(root, title = 'Hello, world')
  app = Demo(root)
  root.mainloop()
basic()
```

Let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the weight of row 0 and column 0 in the master:

```
master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

You are placing that inner `sframe` in row 0 column 0 of `master`, and since that cell has no weight it shrinks up to the upper-left corner. Giving the row and column a weight of 1 makes the column and row fill the available space. Since you aren't using any sticky options for the `sframe`, it will stay centered in its cell rather than filling its cell.